build error react native 0.73.5 * Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.


jni extracted from path C:\Users\NoteBook.gradle\caches\transforms-3\151c442897d359a54d68201b3593536d\transformed\jetified-camera-core-1.5.0-alpha01\jni\riscv64\libimage_processing_util_jni.so is not an ABI

after i delete my project and clone it again i cant build my project anymore
